# Set default action (instead of index) for controller in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller called `Dashboard` with 3 actions: `Summary`, `Details`, and `Status`, none of which take an ID or any other parameters. I want the URL `/Dashboard` to route to the `Summary` action of the `Dashboard` controller, as `/Dashboard/Summary` does, but I can't figure out the correct way to add the route. In `Global.asax.cs`, I have the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "/Dashboard",
    "Dashboard",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Summary" }
    );
```

For the second part, I've also tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "/Dashboard",
    "{controller}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Summary" }
    );
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "/Dashboard",
    "{controller}",
    new { action = "Summary" }
    );
```

but I always get a 404 when trying to access `/Dashboard`. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something about the format for the parameters to `MapRoute`, but I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Move your Dashboard route in front of the Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Dashboard",
    "Dashboard/{action}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Summary" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
);
```

The order of routes changes everything.  Also, notice the changes I made to the `Dashboard` route.  The first parameter is the name of the route.  Second is the URL, which match URLs that start with `Dashboard`, and allows for other actions in your `Dashboard` controller.  As you can see, it will default to the `Summary` action.

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare the "Default" catch-all route last.

Answer (score 1):

This set default Action for any Controller asp.net:

```
routes.MapRoute("Dashboard", "{controller}/{action}", 
defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Summary" });
```