# MVC Controllers from the wrong area being resolved

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given a PhoneCallListController in `/Areas/Contacts/Controllers`

And using a pretty standard ControllerFactory

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext, requestContext, System.Type controllerType)
{
  if (controllerType == null) return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
  return (IController) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
}
```

When making a request to `http://localhost:2663/PhoneCallList`

The `controllerType` passed in is 
    `base = {Name = "PhoneCallListController" 
    FullName = "MyApp.Web.Areas.Contacts.Controllers.PhoneCallListController"`

instead of the null that I was expecting.   I would expect a 404 to occur, but the runtime is happily serving up an instance of this controller, but then failing because `The view 'Index' or its master was not found...` (which makes sense).

By contrast when making a request to `http://localhost:2663/AControllerThatDoesntExsit`, I get a null passed in (as expected) and end up with a 404 (also as expected).

Do I have something configured incorrectly?  Or is there anything in the requestContext I should look at to make sure that the controller and the area in the request info match?

Thanks!

Comment: You're experiencing the standard functionality of the controller factory, see this question for a fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455401/not-including-area-name-in-url-results-in-the-view-index-or-its-master-was-no/18456960

Answer (score 1):

It`s possible that your RouteConfig class has a rule like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is standard ASP.NET MVC behavior.  The default action for a controller is the `Index()` method.

See [Adding a Controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller).

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715667/set-default-action-instead-of-index-for-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-3) for instructions on modifying the default action.

Comment: I would expect this if my controller was in the default controllers namespace/folder, but it's buried in /Areas.